# How to share folders in home network in Windows 7 like we did in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, shared-folders

Since I moved from XP to 7 I don't know anymore how to share folders between Windows 7 machines in a Home Network.

When they share the same Home Network key, they can share special folder like Music, Pictures and Video. But what about common folders?

When I right click a Folder, and share it with Everyone (read permission), the folder isn't visible to other Windows 7 machines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is what you have already done, let me know.  It sounds like you set permissions but not set it as a shared volume.  Full directions are on [this site.](http://www.onecomputerguy.com/windows7/windows7_sharing.htm)

Right click again, go to sharing, specific people, advanced sharing, and check the box for "share this folder" and give it a volume name.