# How to share a Windows 7 folder with vmplayer guest?

Tags: windows-7, vmware-player

The docs say this :

> Check permission settings. Permission settings on the host computer
>   determine access to files in the shared folder. For example, if you
>   are running VMware Player as a user named User, the virtual machine
>   can read and write files in the shared folder only if User has
>   permission to read and write them.

My host is Windows 7. I am running another Windows 7 guest under the username Fake. According to the docs, I have to share my intended folder, say c:\share, by giving Fake the read permission, no? But I am unable to do that as the host says no such user is found. What am I doing wrong?

Daniel.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have a matching user name ("Fake") and password on the share's host computer. Then you can apply the share/file access to that user account.

Check out:

- [How to share folders in home network in Windows 7 like we did in Windows XP?](https://superuser.com/questions/187574/how-to-share-folders-in-home-network-in-windows-7-like-we-did-in-windows-xp)
- [How can I access a shared folder from VMware workstation?](https://superuser.com/questions/292661/how-can-i-access-a-shared-folder-from-vmware-workstation)
- [Windows 7 Professional Network Sharing Permissions](https://superuser.com/questions/316641/windows-7-professional-network-sharing-permissions)